# Refresh DGV after updating or adding a record (Already has a prepall)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

So, I already has function called prepall that refresh the dgv, but when I call this sub from another sub, it does not refresh unless I use the button to prepall.

This is my sub

```
Public Sub prePall()
        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim sx As String = ""
        Dim s As String = "select * from tblQuestionary", sErro As String = ""
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        'GetTable(sx, s, table, sErro, ds)

        If GetTable(sx, s, table, sErro, ds) Then
            gridQuestionary.DataSource = table

        End If

    End Sub
```

This is my button that will call the sub

```
Private Sub CmdPrepall_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrepall.Click
        prePall()

    End Sub
```

This wis a function to delete a record

```
 Function deleteCMD(q As crudDelete) As Boolean
        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        '  Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim s As String
        Dim sql As String
        Dim oledbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

        Select Case q
            Case crudDelete.Questionario
                s = "Select COUNT (*) FROM tblE where IDQuestionary =" & Val(Trim(lblIDQuestionary.Text)) & ""
                Try
                    Using datadapter = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(s, DBconnection)
                        Dim countOfRecords As Integer
                        countOfRecords = datadapter.ExecuteScalar()
                        If countOfRecords > 0 Then
                            MsgBox("Questionary cannot be deleted")
                        Else
                            sql = "Delete * from tblQuestionary where ID=" & Val(Trim(lblIDQuestionary.Text)) & ""
                            deleteRow(sql)
                            cmdPrepall.PerformClick()
                        End If
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(Err.Description)
                End Try
        End Select
        Return True
    End Function
```

I tried to use the button to perform the action, I tried to use directly the sub, but either one did not work. But when I click the button, then the dgv gets updated. I want to refresh without hitting the button, just by calling it from another method.

Comment: Replace `cmdPrepall.PerformClick()` with `prePall()`. This assumes all this code is in the same Form or code page.

Comment: When you called your PrePall directly, did your 2nd GetTable succeed? Do you need two GetTable calls in PrePall?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Sorry, before it was only with one getTable. I tried to do that in the program with 2 getTable, but it was same problem.

Comment: @HardCode I already tried to do with ```prepall()``` same problem

Comment: DId you step through the code calling prepall()? What happens when the line is hit?

Comment: @HardCode it is so weird, bc when I do step by step, and it goes through everything, then it works. But if i do not do step by step, it does not update the dgv.

Comment: You have `If` and `Select Case` that only check for one condition. Maybe the conditions aren't as you expect. Add some `Else` to the Ifs, and `Case Else` to the Select Case. Throw a MessageBox in them. See what happens at runtime.

Comment: @HardCode I tried..it does not go through the else. I am starting to believe it might be something with thread? what do you think?